# verify table data in protractor

Tags: protractor

i want to verify whether the year column is having 2017 or not. below is the screenshot and html snippet    [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDImW.png)

html code:

```html
<table class="htCore table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover"><colgroup><col style="width: 200px;"><col style="width: 200px;"><col style="width: 200px;"><col style="width: 200px;"><col style="width: 200px;"></colgroup><thead><tr><th><div class="relative"><span class="colHeader columnSorting">Year</span><div class="manualColumnMover"></div></div></th><th><div class="relative"><span class="colHeader columnSorting">Created Date</span><div class="manualColumnMover"></div></div></th><th><div class="relative"><span class="colHeader columnSorting">Modified Date</span><div class="manualColumnMover"></div></div></th><th><div class="relative"><span class="colHeader columnSorting">Created By</span><div class="manualColumnMover"></div></div></th><th><div class="relative"><span class="colHeader columnSorting">Modified By</span><div class="manualColumnMover"></div></div></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="htDimmed current fill">All</td><td class="fill">08-Jan-2017</td><td class="fill">08-Jan-2017</td><td class="htDimmed fill">dbo</td><td class="htDimmed fill">dbo</td></tr><tr><td class="htDimmed fill">1986</td><td class="">15-Feb-2017</td><td class="">15-Feb-2017</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td></tr><tr><td class="htDimmed fill">1987</td><td class="">16-Feb-2017</td><td class="">16-Feb-2017</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td></tr><tr><td class="htDimmed fill">1988</td><td class="">16-Feb-2017</td><td class="">16-Feb-2017</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td></tr><tr><td class="htDimmed fill">2000</td><td class="">15-Feb-2017</td><td class="">15-Feb-2017</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td></tr><tr><td class="htDimmed fill">2001</td><td class="">17-Mar-2017</td><td class="">17-Mar-2017</td><td class="htDimmed">Anupama Gopakumar</td><td class="htDimmed">Anupama Gopakumar</td></tr><tr><td class="htDimmed fill">2006</td><td class="">05-Apr-2017</td><td class="">05-Apr-2017</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td></tr><tr><td class="htDimmed fill">2008</td><td class="">05-Apr-2017</td><td class="">05-Apr-2017</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td></tr><tr><td class="htDimmed fill">2013</td><td class="">09-Feb-2017</td><td class="">09-Feb-2017</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td></tr><tr><td class="htDimmed fill">2014</td><td class="">14-Jan-2017</td><td class="">14-Jan-2017</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td></tr><tr><td class="htDimmed fill">2015</td><td class="">14-Jan-2017</td><td class="">14-Jan-2017</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td></tr><tr><td class="htDimmed fill">2016</td><td class="">14-Jan-2017</td><td class="">14-Jan-2017</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td></tr><tr><td class="htDimmed fill">2017</td><td class="">09-Jan-2017</td><td class="">09-Jan-2017</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td></tr><tr><td class="htDimmed fill">2018</td><td class="">09-Jan-2017</td><td class="">09-Jan-2017</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td></tr><tr><td class="htDimmed fill">2019</td><td class="">14-Jan-2017</td><td class="">14-Jan-2017</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td></tr><tr><td class="htDimmed fill">2020</td><td class="">14-Jan-2017</td><td class="">14-Jan-2017</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td></tr><tr><td class="htDimmed fill">2021</td><td class="">15-Jan-2017</td><td class="">15-Jan-2017</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td></tr><tr><td class="htDimmed fill">2022</td><td class="">18-Jan-2017</td><td class="">18-Jan-2017</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td></tr><tr><td class="htDimmed fill">2023</td><td class="">06-Feb-2017</td><td class="">06-Feb-2017</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td></tr><tr><td class="htDimmed fill">2025</td><td class="">06-Feb-2017</td><td class="">06-Feb-2017</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td></tr><tr><td class="htDimmed fill">2026</td><td class="">06-Feb-2017</td><td class="">06-Feb-2017</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td><td class="htDimmed">Ankush Bhatia</td></tr><tr><td class="htDimmed fill">2027</td><td class="">10-Feb-2017</td><td class="">10-Feb-2017</td><td class="htDimmed">Rizwana Haji</td><td class="htDimmed">Rizwana Haji</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

i have tried below solution but not working as expected; can someone take a look?

```html
browser.driver.findElement(by.css('.htCore.table.table-condensed.table-bordered.table-hover')).then(function (table) {
            table.findElement(by.tagName('tbody')).then(function (tbody) {
                tbody.findElements(by.tagName('tr')).then(function (rows) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        rows[i].findElements(by.tagName('td')).then(function (cols) {
                            expect(cols[1].getText()).toMatch('2017');
                        });

                    }

                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can you send me the table html dom along with one <tr> tag open. ?

Comment: this is for one: <tr><td class="htDimmed current fill">1986</td><td class="fill">15-Feb-2017</td><td class="fill">15-Feb-2017</td><td class="htDimmed fill">Ankush Bhatia</td><td class="htDimmed fill">Ankush Bhatia</td></tr>

Comment: @kishan, thanks for looking..

Comment: I want whole table html.

Comment: Meanwhile try this ` for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
          rows.findElements(by.tagName('td')).then(function (cols) {
                 if ((cols.getText()).toMatch('2017'))
                    {
                     console.log("row number" + i + "contains " + cols )
                    }
                 else{
                     break;
                     }
        });`

Comment: the whole html is attached in the question...can you please take a look? i will try this and let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140025/discussion-between-kavitha-and-kishan-patel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in chat:

Please find below workable code:
Negative path :

```
var year = element(by.xpath("//td[text()='20179']")); 

if(expect(element(by.xpath("//td[text()='20179']")).isPresent()).toBe(true))
   { 
    year.getText().then(function(x){ 
    console.log("Year Prevails: " + x); 
   }); 
 } 
 else 
 {
  console.log("Entered Year missing")
 }
```

Positive path :

```
var year = element(by.xpath("//td[text()='2017']")); 

if(expect(element(by.xpath("//td[text()='2017']")).isPresent()).toBe(true))
   { 
    year.getText().then(function(x){ 
    console.log("Year Prevails: " + x); 
   }); 
 } 
 else 
 {
  console.log("Entered Year missing")
 }
```

Comment: one quick question; if the element is not present, say i have passed 20179 it doesnt even go inside the loop and fails the it block with error message  - no element found using element(by.xpath("//td[text()='20179']")
so the error message is not graceful since it is not going to else loop.
any idea how to handle this

Comment: nice one Kishan

Comment: That message will come as it is thrown due to `expect` statement.

Comment: This will shorten your message `if(expect(element(by.xpath("//td[text()='20179']")).isPresent()).toBe(true) == true){`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

expect(browser.driver.findElement(by.css('table tbody tr td:contains("2017")')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);

This will throw either fail of test case when nothing is there or just find that exact element then pass.

Adding the answers given in comments too.

You can try these selectors too.

```
by.deepCss('td:contains("2017")')
or
by.cssContainingText('table tbody tr td' , '2017')
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: thanks @krishnarajanr for looking into it; i have passed it like this  it('verify table contents', function () {
 expect(browser.driver.findElement(by.css('table tbody tr td:contains("2017")')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);

   }) and it failed saying an invalid or illegal selector is specified :( am i missing anything this?

Comment: can you try entering this in browser console and confirm that you are getting the element $('td:contains("2017")')

Comment: Or may the full css selector i gave for you you can enter the whole here and test it. IF the element is returned in you console. Then we are good.

Comment: You can try this selectors too..
by.deepCss('td:contains("2017")')

Comment: by.cssContainingText('table tbody tr td' , '2017')

Comment: $('td:contains("2018")') identified the element as you said and i got one node highlighted in the console; when i pass var ele = element(by.cssContainingText('table tbody tr td', '2018'))
 expect((ele).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);  it says more than one element found and the first will be used; is it right?

Comment: if i give value which is not present, it fails saying no element found using the locator....

Comment: looks like this is working -  var ele = element(by.cssContainingText('table tbody tr td', '2019'))
       expect((ele).isDisplayed()).toBe(true); but it says more than one element found and the first will be used; how can i use print the output and see it is really found/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140056/discussion-between-krishnarajanr-and-kavitha).

Comment: Cool
good to hear that.
You can do one thing, instead of giving as element try element.all()
or element(locator).all()
so you can use .get() to get the index of the elements or you can use .then() to check another level to ensure the element is present

Comment: Also you can use .count() to get the count of if and you can verify the total count with .toEqual().

Comment: This is working but i am facing few issues; the @kishan solution worked perfectly. thanks for taking your valuable time to look into it and giving suggestions on time. Really appreciated.